# How to pass variables to 'use_cols' argument of pd.read_excel

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code as below

`df = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheet_name=sheet_name,skiprows=skiprows, use_cols='A:O')`

This works just fine. However, the columns change from sheet to sheet, hence I want to provide an `input` option to the user where the enter the column names (A,B..) for `from_col` & `to_col` variables & then use those names in the `use_cols` argument.

However, I am not able to use the variable directly in the argument `use_cols`. What I am doing now is as below

```
from_col = 'A'
to_col='O'
a_l = string.ascii_uppercase
w_l=a_l[a_l.index(from_col):a_l.index(to_col)]
df = pd.read_excel(filepath,sheet_name=sheet_name,skiprows=skiprows, use_cols=w_l)
```

Now, the question is, is there a way to pass variables to 'use_cols' argument of pd.read_excel directly? or a simpler way than what I aa using now?

**Update**

The code above that is am using is not working properly, it reads upto column `O` no matter what variable I pass in `from_col` & `to_col`, not sure why. The list `w_l` updates properly, but `use_cols` seems to be ignoring it!

Comment: you can simply use `w_l = f"{from_col}:{to_col}"` but the argument is `usecols`, not `use_cols`

Comment: @luigigi you are right, the argument is `usecols` but it did not throw an error!

Comment: @luigigi your suggestion `f"{from_col}:{to_col}"` works. I did not why i did not think of that! if you can put your solution as answer, i will accept & up-Vote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a string and pass it as an argument like this:

```
from_col = 'A'
to_col='O'
w_l = f"{from_col}:{to_col}"  # 'A:O'
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, usecols=w_l)
```